# Send money request always return BadRequest

Tags: transactions, send, coinbase-api

coinbase api issue
Note : authentication correct and generating an address for the account working correctly.
Error : any transaction based calls coming back with 400:BadRequest
(in this a send call to a generated address on an acccount)

```
Url:
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/ab38c9cc-94fd-5835-833e-6c9c16fe1c77/transactions

Header:
CB-ACCESS-KEY=QbWSXXXXX73s0Ao4
CB-ACCESS-SIGN=b201e63777d786a20XXXXXXXXXX2a4923798ed29a006d87b53575a1e06b65ff0
CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP=1612743335
CB-VERSION=2019-05-31

Post Data: {"type":"send","to":"0xb4Dab637f71f7A9CA34B89ce9Fe267FA1afdC2d1","amount":"0.01","currency":"EUR","idem":"1612743326.61914"}
```

Returned every time : 400, Bad Request

Any help, feedback or info appreciated, this is now a blocker issue. If any more info needed please let me now rather then closing the ticket please

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question?

Comment: Send will return bad request for logical errors as well. The only send functions I did get working is where the crypto address was the same currency as specified on the parameters as well as the source account. I.e can only send amounts in currency that all align in source account, currency specified and crypto address

Comment: Thank you so very much for the information.  I never ever did get it to work.    I literally worked on it for a month and was forced to give up.  Would it be possible to post a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Send Money on the first request will send error code (you will get an sms to the phone number for two factor authentication), then you should perform the same request only this time with the header mentioned in documentation with value token from sms. And as a note I removed the parameter idem, that's when I started getting the sms and think it was code 401.